# How do I view JRE's source code in Eclipse on linux (debian)

Tags: java, eclipse

I have a debian machine. I am using eclipse. Normally on eclipse, to view the source of code of an object, etc, you simply click `F3` on the object. But for some reason, when it's core java classes, I get

```
 "Source not found" and an option to attach the source.
```

Where exactly is the JRE source on debian? When I do a `aptitude search "?provides(java-runtime)"`, the result contains multiple answers with the substring `jre` in it and also no path.

Can someone tell me exactly where to get the source so I can attach it. Also, I would like to make it available to all projects, not just per project.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The `JRE` is purely the runtime environment needed to run Java programs. For the development of Java programs, you need the `JDK` (Java Development Kit).

The JDK itself is split up into several packages, including the JRE, documentation, demos, and the source files.

Assuming that you're using Open JDK 6, `sudo apt install openjdk-6-source` would install and link the source code that you're looking for.

Comment: If you have `openjdk-6-source` installed, the `src.zip` file is in `/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-common/src.zip`.  For `openjdk-7-source` it's in `/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-common/src.zip`.  You can find out the contents of packages with `dpkg -L <packagename>`.

Comment: my jvm dir does not contain `java-6-openjdk-common`. It has `java-6-openjdk`, `java-1.6.0-openjdk`. I use `java-6-openjdk` and so far it has worked. Thanks you !!!

Comment: Works fine for version 7 as well: `sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-source`

Comment: Or `/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386/src.zip` on Ubuntu.

Comment: For me was in `/usr/lib/jvm/openjdk-7/src.zip` (which is linked from other libraries folders) after installing with `sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-source`.

Answer (score 9):

This worked for me in Ubuntu 14.10, Eclipse Kepler using openjdk-8

Window > Preferences > Java > Installed JREs > Click on your java-8-openjdk > Edit

For /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/rt.jar:

set Source attachment to:

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/src.zip
```

set Javadoc location to:

```
file:/usr/share/doc/openjdk-8-doc/api/
```

NOTE: If you don't already have the openjdk-8 java doc, install:

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-doc
```

and for the source:

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-source
```

Answer (score 6):

sudo apt-get intall java-6-openjdk was successful for me on Ubuntu 11.04 LTS. Additionally,if you are using the Eclipse IDE, I went through Window/Preferences/InstalledJREs/java-6-openjdk-amd64/Edit(find rt.jar ) and then Add External File src.zip as shown in the screen shot.[image]

Answer (score 0):

In **Linux**:
Click "AttachSource" ,then select External file location.
**Path**:- Go to *Computer-> usr-> lib-> jvm-> openjdk-8 ->src.zip*

If you do not find openjdk-8 folder. You need to install it.
In Terminal type:-
1) java -version :*Check your java version. (If jdk version is other than 8 change to the appropriate number)*
2)sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-doc : *it is for installing documentation.*
3)sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-source : *it is for installing source file.*

**Source**:- **Bipin Bharathi** YoutubeChannel(Check out his video(Recommended))
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X_NocC2TO2E